# AWK insert line at top of a file

Tags: awk

I would like to get some explanation here!
I'm new to awk and I'd like to know how do I `insert a line at to of a file`.

This is what I've tried so far

file.txt

```
content line
another line
```

awk command

```
awk  'BEGIN {print "first line" } {print}' file.txt
```

the output

```
first line
content line
another line
```

however, when run with `-i inplace` doesn't write to the file only gives me this output

```
first line
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and if you guys can explain it I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BEGIN{}` block is processed ***before*** any files are processed which means any output generated by the `BEGIN{}` block has nowhere to go but to stdout.

To get the line inserted into the file you need to move the `print "first line"` into the main body of the script where it can be processed along with the file.

One idea based on inserting the new row while reading the first line of the input file:

```
$ awk -i inplace 'FNR==1 {print "first line"}1' file.txt

$ cat file.txt
first line
content line
another line
```

**NOTES:**

- `FNR==1` will apply to each file if you happen to feed multiple files to `awk`, otherwise `NR==1` will also suffice if it's just the one input file
- the stand-alone `1` is non-zero and thus considered by `awk` as `'true'`; here it applies against all input lines and the default behavior for a `'true'` is to pass the input line through to stdout (effectively the same as `{print}`)

Comment: I'm thankful @mark-fuso, I was really confused about it. `the BEGIN{} block has nowhere to go but to stdout.`, that means the `END` block as well, right?

Comment: @Minux-Dev  correct, same applies to the `END{}` block; *NOTE:*  `GNU awk` supports `BEGINFILE{}` and `ENDFILE{}` blocks whereby if the extra `print` is in one of these blocks then the output *will* go to the file

Answer (score 2):

The `-i inplace` includes the built-in `inplace.awk` include file to emulate `sed -i` in-place editing but there *are* some caveats that come from the method used for this emulation.

Because it works by fiddling with the processing of each input file (by using the `BEGINFILE` pattern), anything printed in the `BEGIN` selector still goes to the start-up output stream rather than to the "fiddled" output stream. That's because the first input file has yet to begin processing at that point.

So what you'll see is `first line` going to standard output then the two lines from the input file being printed in-place back to that file. You just may not have *realised* that last bit since you don't change the lines in the file when you write them back.

This was no doubt a difficult implementation decision for the creators of `inplace.awk` since in-place editing over *multiple* files needs to be catered for. The question is: where should output go in `BEGIN` for in-place editing?

You have a couple of options here.

---

First, if you know you'll only ever process *one* file, you can use the normal trick, with `BEGIN` but without `inplace`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {print "first line" } {print}' file.txt > /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ file.txt
```

---

Second, using `inplace` but not `BEGIN`, you need to first decide which of the input files it should affect. If you want it to affect *all* input files, that means something like:

```bash
awk -i inplace 'FNR==1 {print "first line";print;next} {print}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you want it to affect just the *first* input file, use `NR` rather than `FNR` (the former never decreases, the latter resets to one for each new input file).

---

Finally, for the case where all files should be affected, you can use the same method that `inplace` itself uses.

As special patterns like `BEGIN` are executed in order of definition (and `-i` comes before processing of your script), simply use `BEGINFILE` rather than `BEGIN`, as per the following transcript:

```bash
=====
pax@styx:~$ cat xx.001
Original line from xx.001

=====
pax@styx:~$ cat xx.002
Original line from xx.002

=====
pax@styx:~$ cat xx.awk
BEGINFILE {
    print "inserted line"
}
{
    print
}

=====
pax@styx:~$ awk -i inplace -f xx.awk xx.001 xx.002

=====
pax@styx:~$ cat xx.001
inserted line
Original line from xx.001

=====
pax@styx:~$ cat xx.002
inserted line
Original line from xx.002
```

The `BEGINFILE` from `inplace` will first weave its magic to capture output (per input file), then *your* `BEGINFILE` will print to that capture area.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```bash
$ awk -i inplace 'NR==1{print "first line";print;next} {print}' file ; cat file
first line
original content line 1
original content line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-awk version:

I was excited to see the `-i inplace` option, but it's not available in  macOS and BSDs. So in addition to @paxdiablo's solution of a tmp file, here's how you can prepend lines with `/bin/ed`.

```bash
ed -s file.txt << EOF
1i
first line
.
w
EOF
```

Comment: Surely macOS and *BSD have the ability to install extra packages (`gawk` in this instance)? That's gotta be better than using an editor that should have gone the way of the dinosaurs as soon as Bill Joy added `ex/vi` way back in (I think) 2BSD :-) Good answer though.